# When I mined my hopper, it didn't drop as an item; was this because I didn't use a tool?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After using my precious iron to build a hopper, I was surprised when I mined it (to move it) and it didn't drop a hopper item. Would this be because I might have done it with bare hands instead of with a pickaxe (or other tool, like an axe)?

Comment: Arperum got in there just as I was typing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. Mining it by hand won't drop anything. You need a pickaxe to get a hopper back. Any pickaxe will do.

source: [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hopper)